# Anyone have any issues with using PLINQO and ASP.NET MVC 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, migration, plinqo

I'm asking because I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 site, thinking of upgrading to ASP.NET MVC 2.0. Then I read that [PLINQO 5.0](http://plinqo.com) was released (I had never heard of PLINQO before) and have been impressed with what PLINQO appears to be capable of.

**1) Is PLINQO capable of building out an ASP.NET MVC 2.0 UI project when it's run?**

**2) Have you had any bad experiences using PLINQO (particularly in an ASP.NET MVC app)?**

Let me make sure I have the scenario right in my mind:

Using PLINQO (assuming it supports ASP.NET MVC 2.0), I should be able to point it to my DB and it will create 3 projects: data, test, and mvc 2.0 UI? The data would contain LINQ to SQL queries, with the PLINQO extensions added in and the other projects setup to use the data project by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm exploring PLINQO 5.0 and here are my answers,

1) No, PLINQO will not build MVC2 UI Project. But the Data project supports MCV2, take a look the latest [Traker](http://codesmith.googlecode.com/files/PLINQO.Tracker-CSharp-v5.0.0.1687.zip) sample application.

2) No and still a better choice comparing to EF4.

HTH

Comment: That's what I was hoping to hear. I'm beginning to use PLINQO now, manually adding the PLINQO generated data-tier into an MVC 2.0 app. Working great so far.

Comment: We also just released a PLINQO for EF and nHibernate :-)